How to kill a process "daemon" in Linux so that it doesn’t restart?
I have a Plesk Linux VPS, there is a process "daemon" in the process list take 40% CPU usage!!



I do kill -9 PID but it regenerates itself after 30 min!
For the server everything is okay. After searching about this daemon process, the server sends a punch of notification messages to server administrator.
Any solution to stop this process?
All of Schedule Tasks as (user:root), I stop notify, I set it "Do not notify".
I tried to stop SMTP Server (Postfix) in the Services, still it regenerates this process itself!
I have already "Immunify" antivirus and all of websites in my server is clean.
In the "Task Manager" there is 13:
FAILURE task: [2024-09-19 ][1] 21:30:51.085] 3683485:66ec7beb097f3 ERR [panel] [66ec7beb09728] Result of interface implementation call: failure: Can not find domain by id 82 Can not find domain by id 82

All of the FAILURE task is same, I have deleted some subdomains, after delete any subdomains it show like this FAILURE task.

Are you experiencing slowness on the processes you WANT this server to be running? As in, is there an actual problem here? 40% CPU usage, on its own, isn't a problem. Learning WHY this particular system process needs that much CPU is what you should be looking into. The OS certainly thinks it needs whatever that process is doing.
